# Error 1217 vs 1452: Still less verbose despite `GRANT_ALL`

Tags: mysql, privileges, mysql-8.0, mysql-error-1452

On MySQL 8.0.34, errors 1217 and 1452 represent the same thing but provide less information in the former case [by design](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99336). A user without the relevant grants should not see the information about a table restricting a delete. In my case, the 'basic' user has access to the database with the restricting table, but still sees the low verbosity error 1217. What grants are required to show this user 1452?

As advanced user, 1452

```sql
mysql> show grants for current_user();
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for advanced@%                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES, SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO `advanced`@`%`    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO `advanced`@`%`                      |
(others removed for brevity)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM `common_a`.`a` WHERE my_field LIKE 'restriction';
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`common_b`.`_b`, CONSTRAINT `_b_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`my_field`) REFERENCES `common_a`.`a` (`my_field`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

As basic user, 1217 despite having all privileges on the `common_` prefix

```sql
mysql> show grants for current_user();
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for basic@%                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES, SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO `basic`@`%`       |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `common\_%`.* TO `basic`@`%`                 |
(others removed for brevity)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM `common_a`.`a` WHERE my_field LIKE 'restriction';
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I have tried...

- Revoking and re-granting the privileges shown above. No change.
- Granting all for  `` `common_a`.* `` and `` `common_a`.`a` ``, and `b` equivalents.
- Cascading my delete with the advanced user. I found no restricting tables outside of the `common_` prefix.
- Granting all for each individual table that would be referenced in this cascading delete, and all databases on the `common` prefix individually
- Granting all to 'basic', as shown in 'advanced' above. This changed the error, but doesn't protect my other databases.
- Asking what grants are needed on the existing [mysql bug thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99336).
- Asking on [stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334167/error-1216-not-1451-despite-reference-privilege-on-mysql-8) months ago with no reply.
- Loading a new instance of our database from mysqldumps.
- Comparing table declarations for tables with and without this bug in mysqldumps.

How can I get the more verbose error while still restricting basic's access outside of `common_`?

Comment: The error shows it is not a privileges issue. You do seem to have the right privileges. The error is caused by a foreign key constraint conflict. You can't delete the row in `common_a.a` because another row in table `common_b._b` exists that references it.

Comment: FYI, using wildcards `%` and `_` in the database name is deprecated.

Comment: @BillKarwin As explained in the linked issue, sometimes you'll get this error if you don't have the `REFERENCES` privilege, which is needed to determine whether the FK exists.

Comment: @BillKarwin but what the question is about is why two different users get a different error for the same operation. One gets 1451, the other gets 1217.

Comment: It looks like the difference is because the FK goes between tables in different databases. I suspect this triggers a bug in pattern matching the privileges.

Comment: You could report this as a bug, but since it involves a deprecated feature I doubt they'll do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! Can you point me to deprecation notes for this? I use `_` in database names, which I thought I escaped in theses grants, but maybe that interferes? Can I not issue grants with wildcards?

Comment: It's in the documentation of the `GRANT` command: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: There's no problem with `_` in database names AFAIK. We've been using it for years, and never needed to escape them.

Comment: It does have a warning about escaping it. That's really only necessary if you have databases that are the same except for a different character in place of `_`. E.g. if you have `foo_bar` and `fooxbar`, a grant for `foo_bar.*` would also allow access to `fooxbar.*`. This is probably extremely unlikely.

Comment: I ran `grant all on common_x.table_y to basic` for each table fk ref'd in this delete, and still getting 1217 on some tables but not others. I'm not fully convinced it's a wildcard issue, but nor do I think I will get very far reporting if I can't replicate in isolation